# ROS2 Humble on Windows 10 - RVIZ2 gives error "Process exited with failure 3221225595"

Tags: ros2, rviz

I am trying to use RVIZ2 on Windows 10 with ROS2 Humble, without much success so far. Running (after activating `local_setup.ps1`):

```
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2
```

Returns with the message:

> [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 3221225595

When running the executable directly:

```
C:\dev\ros2_humble\bin\rviz2.exe
```

I get no messages at all, but the exit code is -1073741701.

I can reproduce this with Windows Sandbox (although the numbers are slightly different), with a fresh and default install of Humble.

ROS2 is working normally and I have installed Qt 5.12.12.
What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer already: I noticed that when I ran `rviz2.exe` directly from Explorer by double clicking I got a bunch of error dialogues about missing DLLs. Unsurprising, because it's missing the ROS2 environment.

So from the ROS2 environment I ran:

```
start C:\dev\ros2_humble\bin\rviz2.exe
```

(I did it without `start ...` before.) Now I got a meaningful error: I got a dialogue with a missing DLL for `zlib1.dll`. After searching I see that `C:\dev\ros2_humble\opt\rviz_ogre_vendor\bin\zlib.dll` *does* exist. So I created a symbolic link for the file `zlib1.dll` to solve this:

```
cd ...
mklink "zlib1.dll" "zlib.dll"
```

This fixed RVIZ2 on my PC!

In the sandbox I have more errors: "OpenGL 1.5 is not supported", but that is outside this scope.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was as Roberto said, but I also needed to copy some `.dll` files such as `OgreMain.dll`, `OgreOverlay.dll`, `assymp-vc140-mt.dll`, `libcurl.dll`, `yam-cpp.dll`, `zlib.dll` from `C:/dev/ros2_humble/opt/{other folder}/bin` to `C:/dev/ros2_humble/bin`
and changing the name of the `zlib.dll`.